# How to fill missing values in DataFrame using another DataFrame in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

my `df` looks like this:

```
sprint   sprint_created
------   -----------
S100     2020-01-01    
S101     2020-01-10
NULL     2020-01-20
NULL     2020-01-31
S101     2020-01-10
...
```

in the above `df`, you can see that some of the `sprint` values are `NULL`

I have another `df2` that has `sprint` date ranges:

```
sprint   sprint_start   sprint_end
------   -----------    ----------
S100     2020-01-01     2020-01-09    
S101     2020-01-10     2020-01-19  
S102     2020-01-20     2020-01-29  
S103     2020-01-30     2020-02-09  
S104     2020-02-10     2020-02-19  
...
```

How can I map these data and fill in the `NULL` values in the `df` by comparing the data in the `df2`?

Please note that the shape of `df` and `df2` are different.

Comment: Are both DataFrames guaranteed to use the same row based index? i.e. row `5` in `df` always corresponds to row `5` in `df2`. Or do you need to match them based on the `sprint_created` and `sprint_started` columns? (which look the same here but may not be). Pandas has good documentation on concatenation and merging: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html

Comment: As I can see, the Sprint column has multiple repeated values in first table. What is the key that you would use to identify  and join a row if your index values dont match between the 2 tables?

Comment: in `df2` yes, since it is providing the value of the `sprint` date ranges. But `df` could be random

Comment: `df` will have multiple same `sprintid` and the key in `df` would be another column which is `project_id`

Comment: In your second dataframe.. your end is before start in last row

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, I updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to `melt` and `resample` your `df2` and create a dictionary to `map` back to `df1`:

```
#make sure columns are in datetime format
df1['sprint_created'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['sprint_created'])
df2['sprint_start'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['sprint_start'])
df2['sprint_end'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['sprint_end'])

#melt dataframe of the two date columns and resample by group
new = (df2.melt(id_vars='sprint').drop('variable', axis=1).set_index('value')
          .groupby('sprint', group_keys=False).resample('D').ffill().reset_index())

#create dictionary of date and the sprint and map back to df1
dct = dict(zip(new['value'], new['sprint']))
df1['sprint'] = df1['sprint_created'].map(dct)
#or df1['sprint'] = df1['sprint'].fillna(df1['sprint_created'].map(dct))
df1
Out[1]: 
  sprint sprint_created
0   S100     2020-01-01
1   S101     2020-01-10
2   S102     2020-01-20
3   S103     2020-01-31
4   S101     2020-01-10
```

Answer (score 1):

I assummed duplicated sprint in df(first dataframe can be dropped). Please advice otherwise if not so. I use merge asof with one day tolerance based on my comparison of the two dfs you provided. Advice otherwise if so

`df.assign(sprint=pd.merge_asof( df.drop_duplicates(keep='first'), df1, left_on="sprint_created", right_on="sprint_start", tolerance=pd.Timedelta("1D"))['sprint_y']).dropna()`

```
  sprint sprint_created
0   S100     2020-01-01
1   S101     2020-01-10
2   S102     2020-01-20
3   S103     2020-01-31
```

If your frame has legit multiple sprints as explained above in comments. Please try;

```
g=df.assign(sprint=pd.merge_asof( df.drop_duplicates(keep='first'), df1, left_on="sprint_created", right_on="sprint_start", tolerance=pd.Timedelta("1D"))['sprint_y'])
g.loc[g.sprint.isna(), 'sprint']=g.groupby('sprint_created').sprint.ffill()
print(g)



sprint sprint_created
0   S100     2020-01-01
1   S101     2020-01-10
2   S102     2020-01-20
3   S103     2020-01-31
4   S101     2020-01-10
```